# Вывести свойство второго уровня из объекта

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты

Есть  объект типа

```
var fruits = {
    apple: {
        id: 1,
        color: "red",
        mass: 22,
    },
    orange: {
        id: 2,
        color: "orange",
        count: 33,
    },
    lemon: {
        id: 3,
        color: "yellow",
        count: 13,
    }
}
```

Как с помощи цикла `for...in` вывести параметры только первого объекта, или только все цвета, `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var fruits = {
    apple: {
        id: 1,
        color: "red",
        mass: 22,
    },
    orange: {
        id: 2,
        color: "orange",
        count: 33,
    },
    lemon: {
        id: 3,
        color: "yellow",
        count: 13,
    }
}

for (var name in fruits) {
  console.log('id: ' + fruits[name].id + ', цвет: ' + fruits[name].color); 
}
```

Только для первого объекта нет смысла использовать `for..in`. Можно брать напрямую.

Ну, если сильно хочется, можно так:

```js
var fruits = {
  apple: {
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    mass: 22,
  },
  orange: {
    id: 2,
    color: "orange",
    count: 33,
  },
  lemon: {
    id: 3,
    color: "yellow",
    count: 13,
  }
}

var i = 0;
for (var name in fruits) {
  if (i == 0)
    console.log('название: ' + name + ', id: ' + fruits[name].id);
  else  
    console.log('id: ' + fruits[name].id + ', цвет: ' + fruits[name].color);
   ++i;
}
```